# Wordpress how to use <a href> in wp_query?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a `wp_query` to list the posts title and excerpt for a subcategory. I want the title to link to its respective post, but unable to figure out how to get the a href working properly in the following code. The link that is being generated from the below code is, `/category/sub-category/the_permalink()`. Any suggestions please?

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title', 'category_name' => 'diet-tips', 'paged' => $paged,'post_type' => 'post' );
$postslist = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $postslist->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $postslist->have_posts() ) : 
        $postslist->the_post(); 

        echo "<div style='border:1px groove gray; margin-bottom:5px;'><h3 class='btposth'><a href='the_permalink()'>";
        the_title();
        echo "</a></h3><div class='btpostdiv'>";
        the_excerpt();
        echo "</div></div>";

        "<br />";
    endwhile;  

    next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $postslist->max_num_pages );
    previous_posts_link( 'Next Entries »' );
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

Thanks for your help everyone, the code that is producing the results I was seeking is this:

```
echo "<div style='border:1px groove gray; margin-bottom:5px;'><h3 class='btposth'><a href='" . get_the_permalink() . "'>";
             the_title(); 
echo "</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to print the word `the_permalink()` as text and not a function. Try this:

```
 echo "<div style='border:1px groove gray; margin-bottom:5px;'><h3 class='btposth'><a href='".the_permalink()."'>";
    the_title();
    echo "</a></h3><div class='btpostdiv'>";
```

Shorter version:

```
echo "<div style='border:1px groove gray; margin-bottom:5px;'><h3 class='btposth'><a href='".the_permalink()."'>".the_title()."</a></h3><div class='btpostdiv'>";
```

Edit: Without echoing functions:

```
 <div style="border:1px groove gray; margin-bottom:5px;">
     <h3 class="btposth"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
 <div class='btpostdiv'>
```

Comment: Hey Jake, appreciate the advice. Getting closer, but still not there yet.  I revised the code to your edit of:      `echo "<div style='border:1px groove gray; margin-bottom:5px;'><h3 class='btposth'><a href='".the_permalink()."'>";
                 the_title(); 
echo "</a></h3><div class='btpostdiv'>";`       What is happening now is the URL that I want as the permalink is being printed out as text, then the border is beneath that, inside the border we have the Post TItle which is permalinked to the current category page and not to it's post URL, followed by the excerpt. Any further thoughts?

Comment: Hi, okay I have added another way of printing what you need to the bottom of my answer. I think maybe this will work. Can you try it?

Comment: Hey Jake, unfortunately I got a server parse error. The code that is fnally working is:     `echo "<div style='border:1px groove gray; margin-bottom:5px;'><h3 class='btposth'><a href='" . get_the_permalink() . "'>";
                 the_title(); 
echo "</a>`       Thanks a lot for your help tho

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<a href='".the_permalink()."'>';
Somelinks
echo '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "<div style='border:1px groove gray; margin-bottom:5px;'><h3 class='btposth'><a href=".the_permalink().">".the_title()."</a></h3><div class='btpostdiv'>".the_excerpt()."</div></div>";
```